# VBA Crawler: Click on button that changes classname

Tags: javascript, html, excel, vba, web-crawler

So, I am fairly new to VBA/HTML, and I was creating a VBA web crawler for work. Everything was going fairly well, until I encountered a button on a page that, once clicked, changes the classname from "dashboard-wrapper transition closed" to "dashboard-wrapper transition open". The button has no ID, or any other identifier.

Once clicked manually, a dropdown menu appears, with additional buttons to click on.

The website is written in Javascript, but the element has no "onclick" or "onsubmit", or anything of that nature.

```
<div class="le bubble-component-container reporting-wrapper dark">...</div>
<div tabindex= "-1" class="reporting-region">
<div>
<div class="dashboard-wrapper transition closed">
```

I have tried many different ways to target the button, but have been unsuccessful. If there is any additional information I can give, please let me know! Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can target elements by class name as well. Or in reference to some other element you do know. (In javascript that is)

Comment: Yes. I should also mention that i have tried:`for each i in ie.document.getelementsbytagname("div") if i.getattribute("class") = "dashboard-wrapper transition closed" then i.click end if next i` - which has worked for every other button on this web page - but those classnames do not change (I don't even know if this is a problem with the classname changing)

Comment: What about checking if the classname contains 'dashboard-wrapper transition' (with indexOf or similar) instead of matching 'dashboard-wrapper transition closed' and 'dashboard-wrapper transition open'. If you can use querySelector in VBA, you can use a selector like `div[class^="dashboard-wrapper transition"]`

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you so much, Shilly!

Answer (score 0):

**CSS selector:**

You can also use the following selector:

```
.dashboard-wrapper.transition*
```

[image: CSS selector]

The `"."` at the start means className.  Then `dashboard-wrapper.transition*` means className with string `dashboard-wrapper.transition` followed by anything.

---

**VBA:**

```
ie.document.querySelector(".dashboard-wrapper.transition*")
```

**Note:**

In addition to the selector given in the comments of:

```
div[class^="dashboard-wrapper transition"]
```

Which means className `"^"` ***starts with***, you could switch to ***contains*** `"*"` using

```
div[class*="dashboard-wrapper transition"]
```